# How to Dismiss Certificate Selection Popup Dialog in Android Chrome Browser permanently

Tags: android, google-chrome, ssl, single-sign-on, android-browser

I am trying to open a webpage in Android Chrome Browser. I get a pop up Dialog with  **Choose Certificate Pop up** in which I have set a certificate (I Have only One Certificate). Whenever I close the browser and open it again I get the same popup which I have to click either **Allow or Deny**. Its a pain if we try to run this selection whenever we re-visit. How can we avoid this (Dialog pop up set up set once and use the same certificate for future requests).

Thanks in advance for sharing your thoughts/pointers

[image]

Comment: It looks as if this may not be supported. I am looking for a similar solution, and found the following bug report that explains Google's thinking here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=445189

If you find a solution I hope you answer your question!