# Android - Programmatically retrieve certificate (manually installed) from keystore

Tags: android, ssl, keystore

On my android device, I manually installed a certificate which goal is to allow me access to a specific website.

When I look in Security -- User certs, I see can see my certificate.

My website is displayed into a webview, so I have to use the following code

```
@Override
public void onReceivedClientCertRequest(WebView view, final ClientCertRequest request) {
    if (mCertificates == null || mPrivateKey == null) {
        loadCertificateAndPrivateKey();
    }
    request.proceed(mPrivateKey, mCertificates);
}
```

In my loadCertificateAndPrivateKey() function, I am to get certificate like this

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore");
if (ks != null)
{
    ks.load(null, null);
    Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();
    while (aliases.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String alias = (String) aliases.nextElement();
        java.security.cert.X509Certificate cert = (java.security.cert.X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);
        if(cert.getIssuerDN().getName().contains("TOTO")){
            mCertificates = new X509Certificate[1];
            mCertificates[0] = (X509Certificate)cert;


            mPrivateKey = ??;

        }
    }
```

But I don't know how to get the private key... 
I tried this way, but key object is null (the same code works when I load my certificate directly from my app)

```
Key key = keyStore.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());
if (key instanceof PrivateKey) {
    mPrivateKey = (PrivateKey)key;
}
```

So I have few questions :

- Is it the correct way to retrieve the certificate ?
- Why is it not possible to retrieve private key with the certificate's password ?
- How to retrieve this privateKey ?

Tkanks for your answers !

Comment: what android version are you targeting?

Comment: I'm testing on Android 6, and it would be good if it could work on android 4.2.2 (but API 17 = no access to AndroidCAStore). But the priority is Android 6

Comment: if you use the certificate only to access your website, you don't need the cert private key. You also shouldn't have the private key installed on android. The private key seems to be missing, and that is ok

Comment: The thing is that if the private key is null or empty in the request.proceed method, I get a 403 forbidden. I've posted a solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the way to do that, hope that it'll help somebody.

I followed [this link](https://nelenkov.blogspot.fr/2011/11/using-ics-keychain-api.html) that explain how to implement the entire processus.

Finally, I've got the code bolow.
First, define a KeyChainAliasCallback and call the KainChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias that display an activity to have the user authorization to access certificates store.

```
KeyChainAliasCallback keyChainAliasCallback = new KeyChainAliasCallback() {
    @Override
    public void alias(@Nullable String s) {
        Log.d(TAG, "selected alias = " + s);
        asyncTask.execute();
    }
};
KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias(this, keyChainAliasCallback, null, null, null, -1, CERT_ALIAS);
```

Then, you're able to retrieve private key and certificates chains from the internal store (you have to use an async function)

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

    private Exception error;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg) {
        try {

            PrivateKey pk = KeyChain.getPrivateKey(mContext, CERT_ALIAS);
            X509Certificate[] chain = KeyChain.getCertificateChain(mContext, CERT_ALIAS);

            byte[] data = "foobar".getBytes("ASCII");
            Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
            sig.initSign(pk);
            sig.update(data);
            byte[] signed = sig.sign();

            PublicKey pubk = chain[0].getPublicKey();
            sig.initVerify(pubk);
            sig.update(data);
            boolean valid = sig.verify(signed);
            Log.d(TAG, "signature is valid: " + valid);

            if(valid) {
                mPrivateKey = pk;
                mCertificates = chain;
            }

            return valid;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            error = e;

            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean valid) {
        if (error != null) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error: " + error.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Signature is valid: " + valid,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mWebView.loadUrl("https://blablabla.com");
        }


    }
};
```

Then, you're able to give certificate with this function :

```
@Override
public void onReceivedClientCertRequest(WebView view, final ClientCertRequest request) {
    request.proceed(mPrivateKey, mCertificates);
}
```

Last thing I have to find is how to display the choosePrivateKeyAlias dialog just one time (the first).

Comment: Thanks alot！not only answered the question but also provided the reference!